# String comparison doesn't work with f.read()

Tags: python-3.x, string-comparison

I have a code where I compare the f.read() string with another string.

```
def compare(str1, file_name):
    f = open("file_path" + file_name, "r")
    str2 = f.read()
    f.close()
    if str1 == str2:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

It returns True even the texts are identical (checked while debugging).
In similar questions, the solution was **strip() or rstrip()**.

I have tried adding **strip(), rstrip()** to the **f.read()** as follows but nothing changed.

```
str2 = f.read().rstrip()
```

I even replaced all '\n' and '\t' characters with `str2 = f.read().replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '')` for both str1 and str2 but didn't work.

I know there are many questions similar to this but no of them solved my problem.

Comment: Try printing the representation and look for invisible characters

Comment: it could be the \r character. try replacing \r\n like f.read().replace('\r\n', '')

Comment: @KannappanSirchabesan Thank you so much that solved the problem. I never thought about '\r'.